# How can set wait time in MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

Currently, I have a problem like this:

I add a new user to a table "users" with status set to "new". Then after 5 - 15 minutes the status is changed to "Em". It's dependent on how large the data is.
I would like to make a wait time in mySQL to get the status "Em".

how can I make a wait condition until it changes status, maybe in 5 minutes it has changed status already. how can I count those waits and get the status in every minute of waiting

You can guild me by Javascript it's okay.

Thank you so much

Comment: Table Users has a datetime or timestamp column?

Comment: Yes, it's does @P.Salmon

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely clear what your request is. But here I can provide you with some insight. If we need to trace the elapsed time since the creation of a new user and calculate how long it still needs for the new user to reach the `em` status, we can use a view. And if we want MySQL to update the status automatically when the time is right, we can use an event scheduler to check periodically.

```
-- Here is the view supposing it takes 600 seconds to reach em since creation
drop view if exists testview;
create view testview as select user_id,user_status,
concat(time_to_sec(now()) - time_to_sec(ts),' seconds have passed since adding the user.') as since_creation,
concat(time_to_sec(date_add(ts, interval + 600 second)) - time_to_sec(now()),' seconds more to reach em status.') as wait_time
from users
where user_status='new';

-- Here is the event scheduler which checks every 10 seconds
set global event_scheduler=on ;
delimiter //
drop event if exists periodic_check //
create event periodic_check on schedule every 10 second starts now() do 
BEGIN
update users set user_status='em' where user_status='new' 
and time_to_sec(date_add(ts, interval + 600 second)) - time_to_sec(now()) <=0;
END//
```